# Calling a Function leading to loading page error

Tags: php, function, runtime-error

```
generate_random_password();

          function generate_random_password()
        {          
             global $random_password;
             $random_password = rand(100000,999999);
             validate_random_password();
             return $random_password;
        } 

          function validate_random_password()
          {
            $sql3 = ("select * from student where rand_passwd='".$random_password."'") or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
            $query3 = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql3);
            $result3=mysqli_fetch_row($query3);

            if($result3 || is_null($random_password))
            {
                  generate_random_password();
            }
          }
```

I tried to generate a random password but if i use validate_random_password then it is showing loading page connection error.I know it seems silly but i am new to php.Thanks in advance

Comment: show you connection to database code

Comment: `$dbc` in your function is not defined.

Comment: `generate_random_password` calls `validate_random_password` which in turn calls `generate_random_password` which calls `validate_random_password` which in turn....

Comment: Hi..It doesnt seem its database connection problem because there are several other queries running in the same file perfectly..

Comment: Once again - `$dbc` in your function is __not defined__.

Comment: Hi u_mulder but it will call generate_random_password from validate_random_password only if condition fails.I have cropped the code $dbc is already defined at the top..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using global variables in the `validate_random_password()` function, you need to define them all as global, particularly this:

```
function validate_random_password()
{
    global $random_password;
```

But this is not a good idea, you can pass `$random_password` as function argument instead:

```
function validate_random_password($random_password)
{
```

Comment: Thanks  @Okneloper its working fine by passing $database_connection and $random_password as variables..